# Amcharts - Pie Chart - Legend on the right on two columns

Tags: pie-chart, amcharts, amcharts4

It's possible to have the legend in two columns when the legend is on the right of a Pie Chart.

Here a not working example :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yWOjPe

With the legend defined as

```
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.position = "right";
```

Comment: I played a bit with your example and the docs, but didn't get a solution. it seems, that left or right positioned legends are single column only. Maybe one of the developers will provide a solution for this.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. In your demo or even in the jsfiddle I just created, the legend is in 2 columns format.

Comment: The legend names in two columns

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a **custom HTML legend**.

Here is a complete example based on [this demo](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/custom-external-legend/):

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);

chart.data = [
  {
    category: "Category 1",
    value: 10
  },
  {
    category: "Category 2",
    value: 20
  },
  {
    category: "Category 3",
    value: 15
  },
  {
    category: "Category 4",
    value: 7
  },
  {
    category: "Category 5",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    category: "Category 6",
    value: 1
  }
];

let pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());

pieSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "category";
pieSeries.ticks.template.disabled = true;
pieSeries.labels.template.disabled = true;

function toggleSlice(item) {
  let slice = pieSeries.dataItems.getIndex(item),
      $item = document.getElementById(`legend-item-${item}`),
      $itemMarker = $item.querySelector(".legend-marker");

  if (slice.visible) {
    slice.hide();
    
    $item.style.color = "silver";
    $itemMarker.style.backgroundColor = "silver";
  } else {
    slice.show();
    
    $item.style.color = $item.dataset.color;
    $itemMarker.style.backgroundColor = $item.dataset.color;
  }
}

function hoverSlice(item) {
  let slice = pieSeries.slices.getIndex(item);
  slice.isHover = true;
}

function blurSlice(item) {
  let slice = pieSeries.slices.getIndex(item);
  slice.isHover = false;
}

chart.events.on("ready", e => {
  chart.customLegend = document.getElementById("legend");

  pieSeries.dataItems.each((row, i) => {
    let color = chart.colors.getIndex(i),
        percent = Math.round(row.values.value.percent * 100) / 100,
        value = row.value;

    legend.innerHTML += `
        <div class="legend-item" id="legend-item-${i}" onclick="toggleSlice(${i})" onmouseover="hoverSlice(${i})" onmouseout="blurSlice(${i})" style="color:${color};" data-color="${color}">
          <div class="legend-marker" style="background:${color};"></div>
          ${row.category}
          <div class="legend-value">${percent}%</div>
        </div>`;
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}

#legend {
  display: flex;
  align-self: start;
  width: 350px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#legend .legend-item {
  margin: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#legend .legend-item .legend-value {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#legend .legend-item .legend-marker {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="chartdiv"></div>
  <div id="legend"></div>
</div>
```